# JPA Entity for Drop Down columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.1.0, I have the following in my `Entity` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product {

private String productNo;
private String productDesc;
private Date deliveryDate;
private Date invoiceDate;
private Integer productCurrencyId;
private String productCurrency;
```

The above will be used in application for displaying records as well as for CRUD operation.

From the above `productCurrencyId` and `productCurrency` will be used in the application for drop down fields for selection of currency

I would like to know whether it is better to have those two in a separate Entity class or use in same `Product` class? Reason why I asked this if it is in same `Product` class how can I query the values for my drop down column for currency?

I am aware that I can use `@NamedQueries` in Product class call `@NamedQuery(name` in `DAOImpl` to retrieve the records for drop down. If I would want to use `@NamedQuery(name` then I have hard code a sql statement right? Are there any ways I to use `@NamedQuery(name`  or some other mechanism to fetch records for currency drop down if I am not using a separate Entity class for drop down values? What is the best approach for such scenarios?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

**Edit 1**

Another question I would like to ask in relation to Entity class is what if I have a few other fields with drop down columns, should I create separate Entity class for all those drop down fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want to store the list of currencies? as Carsten explained they can have their own table in the database (and therefore its own entity) and you will have a @OneToOne relationship between the Product and the Currency:

```
@Entity
public class Product
{
    ...
    private String productNo;
    private String productDesc;
    private Date deliveryDate;
    private Date invoiceDate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="currencyId")
    private Currency currency;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Currency
{
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String currency;
}
```

Then to populate the dropdown you just need to retrieve all the records from the Currency table:

```
TypedQuery<Currency> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Currency c");
List<Currency> query.getResultList();
```

This is convenient because to add currencies you just need to add a record to the Currency table and the dropdown will show the right values.

If your catalog is unlikely to change, instead of a table in the database you could use an enum:

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
    ...
    public enum Gender {male, female};

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
}
```

And to populate the dropdown:

```
Person.Gender.values();
```

So basically it depends if the catalogs are likely to change and how do you want to handle those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to ask one doubt, is it not required to declare `currencyId` in `Product` Entity? Or `@JoinColumn(name="currencyId")
    private Currency currency;` is enough? Thanks

Comment: And another point is in `Currency` `Entity` it should be `currencyId` instead of `id`? That is what we map `onetoone` right?

Comment: OneToOne annotation automatically references the @Id column of the referenced entity, so it's not required to declare currencyId as an int field in the Product entity. JoinColumn is used in this case to specify the name of the join id column in the Product table, but it can be omitted at all to take default naming conventions (something like currency_ID). Id column in Currency entity can take any name, it works because OneToOne looks by default the field annotated with Id no matter its name.

Answer (score 1):

The technical implementation aside I would make an own entity for the currency since it is a business object of its own. And changes to the currencies would not need to be applied to every product. But the personal preference to make it a own entity aside I can't give any real adive on the underlying technical question. :(