# What should be design in spring hibernate when using two drop-down?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have an `Employee` entity with these fields:

- `id`
- `name`
- `age`
- `salary`

I want to add `Country` and states drop-down where country should be auto populated on page load, and on selection of country drop-down, state list should be populated in state drop-down using jquery.

I am making two entities, `Country` and `State`, with a One-to-Many relationship.

How do I associate in main `Employee` table so that on view it is displayed?

Comment: Refer this thread. There is an accepted solution for similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196181/jquery-json-spring-mvc-dynamically-loading-select-options

Comment: It doesn't have details of the hibernate mappings.

Comment: Can someone help here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934174/jpa-entity-for-drop-down-columns