# JPA Entity for Drop Down columns(How to populate the dropdown)

Tags: dropdown

**[I'm in the same boat where this guy was 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934174/jpa-entity-for-drop-down-columns)**

my question is did i do anything wrong here?

```
<select name="gender">
    <c:forEach items="${Person.Gender.values()}" var="type">
        <option value="${type}">${type}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I have a POJO named Account

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    private long AccountNumber;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    …
    And I have a enum 
    public enum Gender {male, female};

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Gender gender;
    }
```

This is the way I’m triying to populate the dropped down list in the jsp, but it is not working

```
<select name="gender">
    <c:forEach items=“${Account.Gender.values()}" var="type">
        <option value="${type}">${type}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

i have tried to use jsp usebean tag to import the class and I’m still not  get expected result. instead i GETjavax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:`

Comment: please chlick on the for better understanding, thank in advance.I'm in the same boat where this guy was 6 years ago

Comment: You should at least write some brief description of your problem in the question, with link as additional explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Entity for Drop Down columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934174/jpa-entity-for-drop-down-columns)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem i (1) - created a getGenderType() and (2)-add use  tag for Account class in the jsp.

```
@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;
    private long AccountNumber;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;

    …
    And I have a enum 
    public enum Gender {male, female};

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Gender gender;
    }
//this will available in the jsp as genderTypes
public List <Gender> getGenderTypes(){
        return Arrays.asList(   Gender.male,
                Gender.female);
}
```

this is the jsp

```
<jsp:usebean id="account" scope="session" class="java.class.Account"/>
    <select name="gender">
        <c:forEach items=“${account.genderTypes}" var="type">
            <option value="${type}">${type}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```